# Metric for K-fold Cross Validation for Regression models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation, k-fold

I wanted to do Cross Validation on a regression (non-classification ) model and ended getting mean accuracies of about 0.90. however, i don't know what metric is used in the method to find out the accuracies. I know how splitting in k-fold cross validation works . I just don't know the formula that the scikit learn library is using to calculate the accuracy of prediction. (I know how it works for classification model though). Can someone give me the metric/formula used by sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score?

Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
def metrics_of_accuracy(classifier , X_train , y_train) :
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
accuracies.mean()
accuracies.std()
return accuracies
```

Comment: Please share your code so that if it's not listed then someone can work it out

Comment: Done, The function calculates 10 values how is each of them found, like if accuracies's first element= 0.9 , what does it mean , which formula is used ?

Comment: Which regression model are you using? Is not clear from the snippet you provided. According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) the `score` is computed using the score method of the estimator. If you want to change it then you can use the `scoring` parameter.

Comment: @balleveryday You are right I am letting the k-fold cross validation method take its default metric and grid searching on this. the grid search by default uses r2_score and I have added it to my answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, sklearn uses accuracy in case of classification and r2_score for regression when you use the model.score method(same for cross_val_score). So r2_score in this case whose formula is
r2 = 1 - (SSE(y_hat)/SSE(y_mean))
where
SSE(y_hat) is the squared error for predictions made
SSE(y_mean) is the squared error when all predictions are the mean of the actual predictions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Also I can use the same metric using sklearn.metrics-> r2_score.
r2_score(y_true, y_pred). This score is also called Coefficient of determination or R-squared.

The formula for the same is as follows -
Find the link to image below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/USaWH.png

For more on this -
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination